# How to create a tar archive without including parent directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar

I would like to tar file and folder which are inside another folder.

For example:

```
mainFolder/subFolder
mainFolder/file
```

I want to tar only `subFolder` & `file` using node-tar.

```
tar.c({
  gzip: true,
  file: 'uploads.tar.gz'
}, ['temp']).then(() => {
  console.log({
    status: 0,
    message: 'Tarball has been created'
  });
});
```

This creates the `tar.gz` file which has temp folder too while extracting.
Please help me.

Comment: I want to do which is equal to `tar -zcvf uploads.tar.gz -C temp .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add multiple files and folders inside the paths array ( see https://github.com/npm/node-tar#high-level-api )

```
tar.c(
      {
        gzip: true,
        file: 'uploads.tar.gz'
        C: 'mainFolder'
      },
      ['subFolder', 'file']
    ).then(() => {
      console.log( {status: 0, message: 'Tarball has been created'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But even this adds the Parent directory in the tarball. I want to exclude parent directory 'mainfolder'

Comment: @AjayKumarSunder so what you want to use is `C:` I've updated the example